# Ionic App - CordovaPush not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have added phone gap push plugin and ngcordova.
The `ngcordova.js` has been imported before `cordova.js`
I am getting `$window.plugin not defined` error in browser which I believe is expected. But I am getting `cannot read property register of undefined` error in app which means `$cordovaPush` is undefined.

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample) tutorial and trying to implement same

```
 angular
    .module('init')
    .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $cordovaPush, $cordovaToast){
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }

        if(window.StatusBar) {
          window.StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        registerForPush();

        function registerForPush(){
          try {

          var config = {};
          //register for push notifications
          if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            config = {
              "senderID": "1232"
            };
          }else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
            config = {
              "badge": "true",
              "sound": "true",
              "alert": "true"
            }
          }

            $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function (result) {
            alert("Register success " + result);
            $cordovaToast.showShortCenter('Registered for push notifications');
            // ** NOTE: Android regid result comes back in the pushNotificationReceived, only iOS returned here
            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
              //register
            }
          }, function (err) {
            console.log("Register error " + err)
          });

          }
          catch(err) {
            alert(err.message);
          }

        }


        // Notification Received
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
          alert(JSON.stringify([notification]));
          if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            if (notification.event == "registered") {
              alert("android notification received token - " + notification.regid);
            }

          }
          else if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
           alert("ios notification received");
          }
        });



        document.addEventListener('resume', function () {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('resume');
        });
        document.addEventListener('pause', function () {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('pause');
        });
        document.addEventListener('offline', function () {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('offline');
        });
        document.addEventListener('online', function () {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('online');
        });
        window.addEventListener('batterystatus', function (status) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('batterystatus', status);
        });

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working by using [Phonegap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

To initiate the push

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345"
    },        
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId this device token is used to send push notifications
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a push app, and got the same error, but not with this plugin:
[Plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

Remove the ng-cordova plugin and try with that one, it will work.

Follow this tutorial for more help: [doc ionic](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-from-scratch)

Comment: I am confused. what do you mean by not using Plugin-push? Can you put some sample code

Comment: I am trying to use native notifications not ionic push!

Answer (score -1):

I have used http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/phonegap-build/PushPlugin to develop pushnotification and it's works well.

First of all,uninstall any other push notification plugin and then try this one.It works.